# Using Django Managers for limiting queries by user

Tags: django

Say I have two types of users: *brief* and *long*.

When a *brief* user logs in, he should only see the most recent 10 Items. When a *long* user logs in, he should see the most recent 30 Items. Otherwise they're very much alike.

I believe I could use Django Managers to implement something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()

class BriefItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(BriefItemManager, self).get_query_set().order_by('date')[:10]

class LongItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LongItemManager, self).get_query_set().order_by('date')[:30]
```

I'm thinking of monkey patching *Item*, perhaps using Middleware, so that the rest of the code is oblivious to whether the user is a *brief* or *long* . *Item*'s *.objects* manager would be set to be either *BriefItemManager* or *LongItemManager* by the time the main code kicks in.

```
if user_type(request.user) == 'brief':
    Item.objects = BriefItemManager()
else:
    Item.objects = LongItemManager()
```

Questions:

- Are Managers the right way to implement this?
- Is monkeypatching *Item*'s *.objects* manager the right way to go? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to monkeypatch that sucker, because once the `Item` type gets created, it's state is then shared between threads, which includes the default manager. It's possible then that you retrieve 10 items, even though the user for the current request is of type `long`, because you have thread contention on the model manager. (see [ModelBase](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py) in the package `django.db.models.base`)

In your case, you'll want to make it very obvious what is it that your doing. This is my best guess:

```
class ItemManager(models.Manager):

    def latest_for_user_type(user_type):
        limit = user_type=='brief' and 10 or user_type=='long' and 30
        return self.get_query_set().order_by('date')[:limit]

class Item(models.Model)

    # ...

    objects = ItemManager()

# views.py

class LatestItemListView(ListView):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return Item.objects.latest_for_user_type(
            user_type=user_type(self.request.user)
        )
```

You might want to implement the `user_type()` logic in `ItemManager`... you might even want to refactor it to be `latest_for_user(user=None, user_type=None)`. This is just the basic idea and there are other ways, such as proxy classes, that are ideal (the only way true way) for overriding model managers.

Managers are the right way to implement anything that operates on collections.